# Does there exist one number in progression that is coprime to all others?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Does there exists at least one number in sequence $n,n+1,n+2 ... n+m $
which is coprime to all the others. $n,m$ are positive integers.

Comment: It depends on $n, m$, of course.

Comment: If $m=1$ or $m=2$ (choose $n+1$) or $n$ is prime, this is trivial. For $m$ sufficiently large in relation to $n$ (e.g. $m=n$) there will always be a large enough prime number $(p\gt \frac {m+n}2)$ in the list. The harder question is whether there are arbitrarily long sequences for which this is not true.

Comment: @Travis: I would say it's not so obvious (although true $-$ see Aravind's answer).

Comment: For $m = 0$ vacuously there is no such number. For $n = 1$, $m > 0$, trivially there is always such a number (namely, $1$).

Comment: @Travis: The question is whether there exist non-empty sequences with _no_ such number. The answer, apparently, is: such an $n$ can be found if and only if $m \ge 17$. ($0$ is not a positive integer, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveInteger.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Order-theoretic_properties).) So you are correct; it was the "of course" that I was objecting to.

Comment: @TonyK That is simply not what OP writes: $n$ and $m$ are integers, and the question as stated is simply whether there exists a number in the given sequence coprime to others. The question of whether, given a particular $m$, there is an $n$ for which the sequence has no such number is much more interesting, and, like you say, the answer is not so obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a relationship between n and m, this is false in general.

Specifically, Pillai conjectured, and proved in "On m consecutive integers - III" 
(http://www.ias.ac.in/j_archive/proca/13/6/530-533/viewpage.html)

that for every m>=17, there exist m consecutive integers (the starting number n may be large) such that none of the numbers is co-prime to all the others.

It is also known (and interesting) that for m=16, there always does exist a number that is co-prime to all the others.

Comment: The smallest example is the numbers $2184,\dots,2200$, no two of which are coprime.